# how to rewrite url with htaccess and keep relative links working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^!([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^!([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^!([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^!([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2
```

In order to rewrite the url from this: */index.php?p=SOMETHING&s=SOMETHING*

To this: */SOMETHING/SOMETHING*

The problem is - I am using relative urls for pretty much everything - css styles, scripts, images, etc.
And the current htaccess rules break the urls, cause they are trying to access files from a realtive path.

So I would like to know if there is any way to be able to still use these rules and keep the relative links working at the same time.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the URI base in the header of your pages. You can add something like this in your page headers (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags:

```
<base href="/">
```

Either that, or you can change all your links to absolute.

Comment: Watch out, `<base>` will also mess with page `#anchors`, they will have to contain the "full relative url" (e.g. `/contacts/#form` rather than just `#form`). I stopped using it when I realized that the problems it caused were greater than those that it solved.